# Using custom ("on the fly") javascript functions on data in command line (node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, command-line, command-line-interface

Is there a way to use javascript functions to "pipe data through"?

Something like

```
$ curl -s https://api.github.com/users/egamma/gists
  | node.exe --magic "JSON.parse(arguments[0]).map(x=>x.files[0].filename + ' -- ' + x.description)"
  | sed -E "s/^.*'(.*) -- (.*)'.*$/\1\t\2/"
test.js
.eslintrc.json  Visual Studio Code default .eslintrc.json
```

or even

```
$ curl -s https://api.github.com/users/egamma/gists
  | node.exe --magic "x=>JSON.parse(x).map(y=>y.files[0].filename + ' -- ' + y.description)"
  | sed -E "s/^.*'(.*) -- (.*)'.*$/\1\t\2/"
test.js
.eslintrc.json  Visual Studio Code default .eslintrc.json
```

or

```
$ curl -s https://api.github.com/users/egamma/gists
  | node.exe --magicJSON "x=>x.map(y=>y.files[0].filename + ' -- ' + y.description)"
  | sed -E "s/^.*'(.*) -- (.*)'.*$/\1\t\2/"
test.js
.eslintrc.json  Visual Studio Code default .eslintrc.json
```

Node.js has `-e` and `-p` which only work as as parameter so I don't know how I could separate data (arguments) and code. Besides using a parameter limits the data length.

The ugly workaround without writing temporary files would be sth like

```
$ node.exe -p "JSON.parse($(curl -s https://api.github.com/users/egamma/gists)).map(x=>x.files[0].filename + ' -- ' + x.description)"
  | sed -E "s/^.*'(.*) -- (.*)'.*$/\1\t\2/"
test.js
.eslintrc.json  Visual Studio Code default .eslintrc.json
```

*(Note I'm using Git Bash on Windows thus `node.exe` as a workaround for https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/3006)*

Comment: Or you could scrap trying to use node and just go with [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/).